# SharePoint 2010. How to add the "Add" button to Calendar view (or add new item using double click on the day)

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am new to SharePoint. Sorry if answer for my question is obvious.
I've created approve absence workflow, InfoPath forms for adding absence statement and  calendar view to show planned absences.

Now I want to add posibility of adding new absence statement by clicking on the calendar view. But I don't know how to achieve it. I can't see the "Add" link in calendar view. I can add New item by clicking button in the ribbon, but I want to do it by double clicking on calendar. 
Is it possible?

I know that I can use Event content type to use it in Calendar lists, but in this case I can add new event by double clicking, but I can't customize form using InfoPath.

I am googling about ways to solve my problem, but unfortunately I can't find any information about my needs.

**Is it possible to add new item in calendar view by double-clicking on day and customize new item form using InfoPath?**

Every suggestions are very appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

**Update1:** Also I tried to use Calendars overlay to show my absences in calendar view, but also I can add new item with all necessary fields by double-click, but I don't know how to customize it using InfoPath.